# Logging out using nested promises

Tags: javascript, error-handling, angular.js, authentication, promise

Is it OK to do that ?

for example, I have my log out service

```
  logout: function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    this.getCustomer().then(function(credentials) {
      $http.post(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/auth/logout',
      {username: credentials.username, customer: credentials.customer}
    ).success(function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
          defer.reject(data);
        }
        LocalForageFactory.remove(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_CUSTOMER).then(function() {
          /*Removing LocalForage Items*/
          cleanLocalForage();
          defer.resolve(data);
        }, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          defer.reject(data);
        });
      }).error(function(data) {
        cleanLocalForage();
        defer.reject(data);
      });
    }, function(err) {
      defer.reject(err);
    });
    return defer.promise;
  },
```

and then I have a function in a controller which returns an error once the session expires. When the session expires I need to logout the user and redirect him to the login path. So, this is what I have so far:

```
$scope.removeSlip = function(slip) {
  BetSlipFactory.removeSlip(slip).then(function() {
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    AuthFactory.logout();
    $location.path('/');
  });
};
```

or should I do something like this with the logout promise into the `BetSlipFactory.removeSlip()` promise ?

```
$scope.removeSlip = function(slip) {
  BetSlipFactory.removeSlip(slip).then(function() {
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    AuthFactory.logout().then(function() {
     $location.path('/');
    })
  });
};
```

there is my question: what is the proper way in this case ?

Comment: The first version sets the path to '/' immediately after calling logout while the second version waits for the logout to complete before redirecting. Since I don't know how the logout works I can't tell you if it's necessary to wait for it to complete. But I can see that you are not using promises consequently. It's not necessary to have that many error handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Promises are designed so that you won't have to nest at all! You can think of Promises as try-catch-finally statements. And the nice thing about Promises is that if you return a promise inside `then`, the next chained `then` waits for that promise instead of the original. Here's a simplified version of your code (assuming I understood it correctly).

```
// Call the async function #1
return this.getCustomer().then(
  function(credentials) {
    // Success for async function #1

    // You can return promises. It will be listened to in the next .then()
    return $http.post(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/auth/logout', {
      username: credentials.username,
      customer: credentials.customer
    });

  }
).then(
  function(data) {
    // Success callback for async function #2 (the POST request)

    // We can also return a newly rejected promise to fail the next then
    // Or send back the promise of your remove operation
    // $.Deferred().reject().promise(), Deferred is read-write, Promise is read-only
    return data.error ? new Promise.reject() : LocalForageFactory.remove(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_CUSTOMER);

  },
  function(error) {
    // Fail callback for async function #2 (the POST request)

    cleanLocalForage();
  }
).then(
  function() {
    // Success callback for async function #3 (the remove)

    cleanLocalForage();
  },
  function(err) {
    // Fail callback for async function #3 (the remove)

    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

The return value is either a resolved or rejected promise, depending on the result of the entire chain. If the entire thing resolves, the return is a resolved promise. If it rejects, then it returns a rejected promise. You can also recover from a reject by returning a promise. If that promise resolves, the next chain resolves and so on.

It's the main reason why it's called "then". It's like "Do this, *then* what?". The idea of the promise is to be some sort of linear flow-control mechanism, to avoid nested callbacks and proxy deferreds.

As for the other function, assuming `logout` is an async operation, you can do it like:

```
BetSlipFactory.removeSlip(slip).then(null, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  return AuthFactory.logout();
}).then(function() {
  $location.path('/');
});
```